# Modern page Highlight Content Type - Sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages

Is there a way to configure the Highlight Content add-in to show a list of subsites only?

We have a Customers site with a subsite for each customer which is what we'd like to show up in Highlight Content on the home page of the Customers site.

So far I've set the Source to This Site (and tried Site Collection), but Type doesn't have an option for Sites.

My next option was to set Type to All and then I thought I could somehow filter the results based on a Managed Property of some sort but this is as far as I got.

Any ideas? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need it to be dynamic you can just create a filter based on Managed Property, and then select "Path" then 'Contains'or 'Equals' and set it to the subsite's path.

Should be easy enough. Be careful with Highlighted Content web parts though, if you select more than one filter, it will display all documents that have EITHER tag, rather than displaying only documents that have BOTH tags. 
So the filters act with an "Or" function rather than an "and". 
Given that this question is 5 months old, you probably already figured that out. 
If you have and you're as annoyed as I am with it, please vote here: https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/264636-general/suggestions/32071210-highlighted-content-web-part-allow-multiple-fil